# UISlider with step like in Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I'm working on a Xcode project and I need to create a **UISlider with 5 steps** to rate something. I know this kind of slider exist natively because Apple uses it in *Settings > General > Text Size*. I can't post images but I hope you know what I'm speaking.

I searched on Google but I found nothing...
Thank you for your help !

PS: Sorry for my bad english but I'm french

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, never assume something is available, simply because it exists in an apple developed app. This is far from the truth. Sadly, they have held back a great many things.

To address your issue, try this (set slider min to 0 and max to 5 or whatever you want):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

This should allow the slider to pop to 0,1,2,3,4, and 5. (don't forget to replace my variable names with your own)

Hope that helps, happy coding.

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)mySlider { 
     mySlider.value = round(mySlider.value); 
     self.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", mySlider.value]; 
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick - this code will allow the slider to pop to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 (assuming a min of 0 and max of 5).

Comment: Haha, I knew this when writing it, but I am at work, and was just trying to get him a quick solution. Thank you for the accuracy sir. :)

Comment: OK, thanks to you for your help ! I have just a last question:
Is it possible to add vertical lines to symbolise the value like Apple do ?

Comment: What about the design bit of it? I mean the steps being visible on the slider. Is there's a quick tip for it or is it something that requires some hardcore coding?;)

Comment: @Noah did you find solution for design, i also need same design like setting.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the answer posted by @williamriley, after you enable the "popping" functionality, you can setup the code for each increment of the `UISlider` with the following code (inserted into the `.m` file):

```
- (IBAction)speedButton
{
   if(speed.value == 1)
   {
      // insert code here..
   }
}
```

You would create the button in the `.h` file, and assign it to the `UISlider` through a value changed assignment. Copy and paste this code 5 times for each increment of the slider. Obviously, there are more efficient ways of doing this, but this is just my two cents.